# Kendo calendar selected date event

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, kendo-ui

Hi I've a kendo calendar and a text box in my page. When I select any date on the calendar, I wanted to show that value in my textbox. (like datetime picker). Any way to get it?

Here is my sample code

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
<input type="text" name="txtdate" id="txtdate"/>

 <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    // create Calendar from div HTML element
                    $("#calendar").kendoCalendar();
                });

                var cal = $("#calendar").data("kendoCalendar");

                cal.bind("change", function () {
                    // Here I wanted to bind the selected value to my text box (txtdate).                      
                });
  </script>
```

Comment: Please use this one for getting the value of the calender, var calendar = $("#calendar").data("kendoCalendar");

// get the value of the calendar.
var value = calendar.value();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   var textVal =  $(this).value();
   $('#txtdate').val(textVal);
```

Comment: Please use this one  :  this.value();