# how to get current day of Kendo calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, kendo-ui

Is there any way get selected day of calendar? to get alert when i navigate from monday to tuesday as "Tuesday".

I know this example is similar to my question.

[jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/jf2XK/](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/jf2XK/)

```
$("#cal").kendoCalendar({
    navigate: function () {
        var cur = this._current;
        var prev = this._previous;
        if (prev && cur && prev.getFullYear() !== cur.getFullYear()) {
            alert("year change");
        }
        this._previous = this._current;
    }
})
```

But I'm new to jquery and mvc,. Please help.

**Update:I need to get the day as I need to fix numbers 1 to 7 for each day of the calendar.**

```
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_getday
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519284/kendo-calendar-selected-date-event

Comment: I seen it @DarkAshelin.Getting date seems to be easier.
, but can you help me in getting change day event,

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the ['change' event](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/calendar#events-change) to get the new value every time it changes?

http://jsfiddle.net/jf2XK/4/

```
$("#cal").kendoCalendar({
    change: function(e){
        alert(this.value()); // your value is here
    }
})
```

Or else just use the 'value()' method --> http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/calendar#methods-value

Comment: thank you Antonis for you response.
 but my main target is to get the day from calendar, as I need to append a note(i.e weekly note for every monday ,tuesday and tilll 7 days in a week)

Comment: the value is there, you can manipulate it however you like. I showed you how to get it whenever it changes, and also how to get it in any other moment you want. Go to the kendo calendar API to see more details if you want.

Comment: The value you get has nothing to do with jQuery. jquery is only used to get the element that will be used by Kendo to make the calendar ( or any widget ) that's why they made their 'constructors' as jQuery widgets. 
You can get the kendoCalendar object for example by using jQuery --> `var myCalendar = $('#myCalElementId').data('kendoCalendar'); // here you have the complete kendoCalendar object and you can call any method you want.`