# kendo calendar get value

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, calendar

I am new in jquery. How can i get kendo calendar value and displayed to the input field?

I know this is duplicate of

[Kendo calendar selected date event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519284/kendo-calendar-selected-date-event)

But i can not understand.

http://jsfiddle.net/d1mkvtga/

```
$("#calendar").kendoCalendar({
   selectable: "multiple"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All I've done is to use the links you've posted. You had the answers right in front of you.

```
// create Calendar from div HTML element
var cal = $("#calendar").kendoCalendar({
  selectable: "multiple",
  change: function() {
    var textVal = this.value();
    console.log(textVal);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`onChange`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/calendar/events/change) event for kendo calendar.

**Code Snippet**

```
 // create Calendar from div HTML element
 $("#calendar").kendoCalendar({
   selectable: "multiple",
   change: onChange
 });

 function onChange() {
   let v = kendo.toString(this.value(), 'd');
   console.log("Change :: " + v);
   $("#daterange").val(v);
 }
```

You can check here with this working [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yj4bLrw0/).

Comment: correct. But single date only displaying. But I dragged multiple dates.